# Splitting a String and increment in ant

Tags: ant

there are different folders or strings like **4.5, 4.10.1, 4.10.2, 4.10.5, 4.11.1, 4.12 , 4.13.2**...etc

My input will be **4.10.1 to 4.11.1** and it should fetch only the respective strings.

I should be able to get an **output like 4.10.1, 4.10.2, 4.10.5, 4.11.1.**

Now, am able to split the strings, but not possible to increment to get the next strings.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough details (what means respective ..), but basicly you'll need some kind of looping.
Either use ant [script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) with a scripting language, like javascript (already contained in JDK >= 6) or [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) or use some Ant addon like f.e. Flaka or [Antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/).
Some basic snippet with [Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) :
Use for task combined with split function to iterate over your list

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

<property name="whatever" value="4.5,4.10.1,4.10.2,4.10.5,4.11.1,4.12,4.13.2"/>

<fl:for var="substring" in="split('${whatever}', ',')">
 <!-- do something with substring ...-->
 <fl:echo>#{substring}</fl:echo>
</fl:for>

</project>
```

For further snippets see [FlakaExamples](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/FlakaExamples) and [Flaka Manual](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/Manual).